# String Split для SQL server 2014

Tags: sql, строки, split

Дано: контактная информация. Местами в поле сайт вместо одного значения несколько с разделителями типа | иногда . Хочется "спасти" эту информацию путем создания строки, полностью повторяющей все поля материнской строки кроме поля "сайт", которое будет разным вдочерних строках.
[image: Как это выглядит в таблице]

Функция String Split не работает, она с 2016 версии.

Из найденного есть такой вариант:

```html
Declare @products varchar(200) = '1|20|3|343|44|6|8765'
Declare @individual varchar(20) = null

WHILE LEN(@products) > 0
BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('%|%', @products) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = SUBSTRING(@products,
                                    0,
                                    PATINDEX('%|%', @products))
        SELECT @individual

        SET @products = SUBSTRING(@products,
                                  LEN(@individual + '|') + 1,
                                  LEN(@products))
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @individual = @products
        SET @products = NULL
        SELECT @individual
    END
END
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5493510/turning-a-comma-separated-string-into-individual-rows

Comment: [1](http://www.rsdn.org/forum/db/6246582), [2](http://blogs.rsdn.org/sql/6380659), [3](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amitjet/2009/12/11/convert-comma-separated-string-to-table-4-different-approaches/)

Comment: Благодарю за ответы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не понятно что вам нужно. Если splitstring, то есть такая реализация:

```
--разбивает строку на таблицу
--select * from dbo.fnSplitString('1|20|3|343|44|6|8765','|')
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] ( @source VARCHAR(MAX), @delimiter varchar(1))
RETURNS
 @returnList TABLE (item varchar (max), ind int)
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @name NVARCHAR(255)
 DECLARE @pos INT
 DECLARE @index INT = 0

 WHILE CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @source) > 0
 BEGIN
  SELECT @pos  = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @source)  
  SELECT @name = SUBSTRING(@source, 1, @pos-1)

  INSERT INTO @returnList 
  SELECT @name,@index

  SELECT @source = SUBSTRING(@source, @pos+1, LEN(@source)-@pos)

  set @index=@index+1
 END

 INSERT INTO @returnList
 SELECT @source,@index

 RETURN
END
```

Comment: Отличная вещь, спасибо.